# Display records on index page with Elixir and Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to use a comprehension to display a records from the database. But I can't quite `Comprehend` (Bad Joke) what is going wrong? The error message, while I'm sure it's telling me what is wrong, I don't understand what it's trying to say.

#### ERROR:

```
UndefinedFunctionError at GET /leagues
function Statcasters.Schema.League.fetch/2 is undefined (Statcasters.Schema.League does not implement the Access behaviour)


%Statcasters.Schema.League{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "leagues">, id: 1, inserted_at: ~N[2017-11-22 03:36:47.999950], name: "nae", teams: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :teams is not loaded>, updated_at: ~N[2017-11-22 03:36:47.999956], user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>, user_id: 1}
```

#### VIEW:

```
<h1>Join a League</h1>

<%= for league <- @leagues do %>
  <%= league["name"] %>
<% end %>
```

### MODELS:

#### LEAGUE:

```
defmodule Statcasters.Schema.League do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto
  import Ecto.Changeset
  import Ecto.Query

  schema "leagues" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :teams, Statcasters.Teams.Team
    belongs_to :user, Statcasters.Coherence.User

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
      |> cast(params, [:name, :user_id])
      |> validate_required([:name, :user_id])
  end
end
```

#### USER:

```
defmodule Statcasters.Coherence.User do
  @moduledoc false
  use Ecto.Schema
  use Coherence.Schema

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
    coherence_schema()
    has_many :leagues, Statcasters.Schema.League

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, [:name, :email] ++ coherence_fields())
    |> validate_required([:name, :email])
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
    |> validate_coherence(params)
  end

  def changeset(model, params, :password) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(password password_confirmation reset_password_token reset_password_sent_at))
    |> validate_coherence_password_reset(params)
  end
end
```

#### LEAGUE CONTROLLER:

```
  def index(conn, _params) do
    leagues = Repo.all(League)

    render(conn, "index.html", leagues: leagues)
  end
```

Again, all I'm trying to do is list all the leagues in the system by name on the league index page. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace this line:

```
<%= league["name"] %>
```

with this:

```
<%= league.name %>
```

`league` is a struct, and to be able to read it's attributes, you need to use dot-notation.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different approaches to solve this problem.

**1.** The simplest one would be to just use a dot notation, as shown by @PawełDawczak since structs in Elixir do not implement [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#content) behaviour out of the box:

```
league.name
```

**2.** Bare maps do implement `Access`, though, and in a case when field names are dynamic, one might opt in for converting the struct into a bare map with [`Map.from_struct/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#from_struct/1) to access attributes with an `Access` behaviour:

```
Map.from_struct(league)[:name]
```

**3.** The third approach would be to implement the access behaviour for your struct:

```
defmodule League do
  defstruct ~w|name|a

  @behaviour Access

  def fetch(term, :name), do: term.name
  def fetch(term, "name"), do: term.name
  def fetch(term, name), do: raise KeyError, "no #{name} key"

  def get(term, :name, default), do: fetch(term, :name)
  def get(term, "name", default), do: fetch(term, :name)
  def get(term, _, default), do: default

  def get_and_update(data, key, function), do ...
  def pop(data, key), do: ...
end
```